# Me solicita algunos datos pero al imprimir los cálculos salen erróneos

Tags: c

Estoy intentando hacer una matriz donde me presente los datos declarados en las variables **ID, sueldo_bruto, estado_civil, AFP, ARS, ISR y sueldo_neto** en la parte de arriba, pero al ejecutar sólo me solicita algunos datos del primer ciclo y luego se llenan todos los campos automáticamente con los cálculos erróneos.

¿Qué error lógico tengo?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

float calculo ();
float imprimir ();

int main (){
    int ID,sueldo_bruto;
    char estado_civil;
    float descuento_1=0.0287,descuento_2=0.0304,descuento_3=0.05;
    float AFP,ARS,ISR,sueldo_neto;
    int empleado[2][2],i,j;


    for(int i=0;i< 1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j< 2;j++){
        printf("Digite el ID del empleado %i:",i+1,j+1);
        scanf("%i",&ID,&empleado[i][j]);
        printf("Digite el estado del empleado %i:",i+1,j+1);
        scanf("%i",&estado_civil,&empleado[i][j]);
        printf("Digite el sueldo bruto del empleado %i: ",i+1,j+1);
        scanf("%.2f",&sueldo_bruto,&empleado[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

float calculo () {

    float AFP= sueldo_bruto*descuento_1;
    float ARS=sueldo_bruto*descuento_2;
    float sueldo_neto=sueldo_bruto - (AFP + ARS + ISR);


    if (sueldo_bruto >= 35000) {
        ISR= sueldo_bruto*descuento_3;
        printf("ISR: %d \n", &ISR);
    }

    for (i=0; i < 2; i++){
        for(j=0;j< 2;j++){

            printf("ID del empleado %i: %d\n",i+1,j+1,ID,empleado[i][j]);
            printf("Estado del empleado %i: %c\n",i+1,j+1,estado_civil,empleado[i][j]);
            printf("Sueldo bruto del empleado %i: %.2f\n",i+1,j+1,sueldo_bruto,empleado[i][j]);
            printf("El AFP es %i: %d\n",i+1,j+1,AFP,empleado[i][j]);
            printf("El ARS es %i: %d\n",i+1,j+1,ARS,empleado[i][j]);
            printf("El ISR es %i: %d\n ",i+1,j+1,ISR,empleado[i][j]);
            printf("El sueldo neto es %i: %d\n",i+1,j+1,sueldo_neto,empleado[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

float imprimir (){

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Porque hay una funcion dentro de otra funcion? esto es c o c++?? por favor utiliza la etiqueta correcta. Y de paso, acostumbrate a usar {} en tu codigo siempre.. hay un for que engloba a otro for, pero si por casualidad te confundiste con las llaves, entonces no lo engloba mas... arregla todo eso, y vemos si realmente tenes un problema...

Comment: ¿Qué hace o debería hacer cada función?, ¿el ISR se muestra solo cuando se cumple la condición? Más detalles ayudarían.

Comment: Primero que nada, el codigo que publicaste no compila. Puedes asegurarte de que
podamos reproducir el problema con el codigo que nos das? Eso incluye
especificar que entradas le diste, la salida que obtuviste, y la salida que
esperabas.

Answer (score 0):

El `array` `empleado` solo toma valores de tipo `int`, y le estas pasando un `char` por medio de un formato `%i`, ademas de que la cantidad de argumentos después del primero que esperan las funciones `printf()` y `scanf()` dependen del numero de especificadores de formato `(%i, %c, %d, %s...)`, y le estas agregando mas argumentos que especificadores como es el caso de  `scanf("%i",&ID,&empleado[i][j]);` (1 solo especificador pero 2 argumentos después), el valor obtenido de `%i` sera almacenado en `ID`, pero el valor de  `empleado[i][j]` sera un valor completamente inesperado y esto pasa igual con todos los demás... y por ultimo pero no menos importante ya que todo esto ocurre dentro del segundo `for` cada vez que haces `empleado[i][j]` estas agregándole un valor y después reemplazándolo por otro una y otra vez, es decir, si en en el primer `scanf()` colocas *10* y en el segundo colocas *2* `empleado[i][j]` almacenara primero el número *10* y luego el 2 en el mismo espacio.

Sinceramente te recomiendo repasar sobre [especificadores de formato](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/format-specifiers-in-c/) y [ciclo for](http://codigoprogramacion.com/cursos/tutoriales-c/ciclo-for-en-c-y-ejemplos.html) y después recrear el código (a partir del primer `for`)

Esto va para el código dentro del `main()`, como en ningún momento es llamada la función `calculo()` simplemente la ignore, pero varios puntos que mencione también aplican para esta.

Comment: El formato `%i` lee enteros, no caracteres. Si añades argumentos de mas en el
`scanf` simplemente se les ignorara, no les dara un valor inesperado.

Comment: Sobre lo primero, por eso hago énfasis en que esta tratando de guardar un dato con un formato `%i` en `char` porque la variable donde lo esta guardando es de tipo `char`, y sobre lo segundo, tienes razón anoche con el sueño me hice malentender jajaja quise decir que el valor que tendrá `empleado[i][j]` sera inesperado al tratar de recuperarlo pues no se le asignó ninguno

Comment: Me disculpo por lo primero, habia entendido que estabas diciendo que `%i`
regresaba un char. No me fije que en el codigo OP esta leyendo un entro a
`estado_civil`.